# Membership vs ticket

Tags: word-choice

Tickets are sold for concerts, presentations and other gatherings. Yet conventions tend to sell memberships. Why does one purchase a membership (rather than a ticket) to a convention?

Comment: sometimes conventions are invite only or closed to general public, thus you need membership to come.

Comment: What @SaUce said. *Political* conventions in particular would probably be likely to identify themselves as such so they can easily/legally exclude troublemakers from opposing parties, hostile reporters, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conventions are, by implication, a gathering of related persons.  Oftentimes, they are held annually as a "private" gathering of some association or another, but their admittance requirements are fairly simple and you can purchase a "membership" at the door.

Note that not all conventions sell "memberships."  And sometimes, even the membership itself is only the purchase item, and you need a separate "ticket" for admittance to the convention.